# How to filter 2 comboboxes based on the selection in 1 combobox?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, combobox, oledb

I have 3 tables:

1) House:

```
| ID_house | House_names | num_region |
---------------------------------------
|   int    |    names    |    int     |
```

num_region - a foreign key, which equals to a primary key(Region.ID_region) in Region table.

2) Region:

```
| ID_region | Nameofregions | num_arearegion |
---------------------------------------------
|   int     |    names      |      int       |
```

num_arearegion - a foreign key, equals to primary key(Areas_InRegion.ID_areas) in Areas_InRegion table.

3) Areas_InRegion:

```
| ID_areas | Area_names |
------------------------
|   int   |    names   |
```

In the form I have 3 comboboxes:

1) cmbHouse - for showing names of houses from House table.

2) cmbRegion - for showing names of regions from Region table.

3) cmbArea - for showing names of areas in regions from Areas_InRegion table.

I populate comboboxes like this:

```
    //cmbHouse
    string cmbHouse_query = "SELECT * FROM House";
    OleDbDataAdapter dahouse = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmbHouse_query, connection);
    DataTable tablehouse = new DataTable();
    dahouse.Fill(tablehouse);
    cmbHouse.DataSource = tablehouse;
    cmbHouse.DisplayMember = "House_names"; 
    cmbHouse.ValueMember = "House.num_region";
    cmbHouse.SelectedIndex = -1;

    //cmbRegion
    string cmbRegion_query = "SELECT * FROM Region";
    OleDbDataAdapter daregion = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmbRegion_query, connection);
    DataTable tableregion = new DataTable();
    daregion.Fill(tableregion);
    cmbRegion.DataSource = tableregion;
    cmbRegion.DisplayMember = "Nameofregions";
    cmbRegion.ValueMember = "Region.ID_region";
    cmbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1;

    //cmbArea
    string cmbArea_query = "SELECT * FROM Areas_InRegion";
    OleDbDataAdapter daArea = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmbArea_query, connection);
    DataTable tablearea = new DataTable();
    daArea.Fill(tablearea);
    cmbArea.DataSource = tablearea;
    cmbArea.DisplayMember = "Names_OfAreas";
    cmbArea.ValueMember = "Areas_InRegion.ID_areas";
    cmbArea.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Combobox cmbRegion has valuemember as the primary key.

I can filter cmbHouse combobox by the primary key as valuemeber in cmbRegion combo, but I can't filter cmbArea combobox.

```
    private void cmbHouse_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbHouse.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            //DataRow selectedDataRow = ((DataRowView)cmbHouse.SelectedItem).Row;
            int num_region = Convert.ToInt32(cmbHouse.SelectedValue);

            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
            com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Region WHERE Region.ID_region=" + num_region.ToString() + "";
            //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("House.num_region", typeof(int));
            OleDbDataAdapter danum_region = new OleDbDataAdapter(com.CommandText, connection);
            DataTable tablenum_region = new DataTable();
            danum_region.Fill(tablenum_region);
            cmbRegion.DataSource = tablenum_region;
            cmbRegion.DisplayMember = "Nameofregions";
            cmbRegion.ValueMember = "Region.num_arearegion";
            //cmbRegion.SelectedIndex = -1;
            if(cmbRegion.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                int num_area = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRegion.SelectedValue);

                OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand();

                com2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Areas_InRegion WHERE Areas_InRegion.ID_areas=" + num_area.ToString(); // + num_area.ToString() + " ; WHERE Region.num_arearegion=@Areas_InRegion.ID_area
                                                                                                                        //com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Areas_InRegion.ID_area", num_area);
                OleDbDataAdapter danum_area = new OleDbDataAdapter(com2.CommandText, connection);
                DataTable tablenum_area = new DataTable();
                //tablenum_area.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Areas_InRegion.ID_areas=" + num_area.ToString();
                danum_area.Fill(tablenum_area);

                cmbArea.DataSource = tablenum_area;
                cmbArea.DisplayMember = "Names_OfAreas";
                cmbArea.ValueMember = "Areas_InRegion.ID_areas";
                //cmbArea.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }                
    }
```

For this, it is necessary that there was another valuemeber as a foreign key [Region.num_areas].

Is it possible to have multiple valuemembers in every single combobox?

When I click on any of the comboboxes, other comboboxes should be filtered.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Let me understand your relationships. _An house is located in a region (1-1 relationship), a Region can have one or more Areas (1-n relationship), an Area belongs to one and only one Region._ I see you are stuck on this problem for a few days and you have asked a lot of questions about this _selection_ problem, but if I am right you need to right your relationships before.

Comment: @Steve An house is located in a region (1-1 relationship), a Region can have one or more Areas (1-n relationship), an Area belongs to one and only one Region. - is correct.

Comment: Relationships between tables is correct, but can combobox contains multiple valuemembers?

Comment: No there is not such functionality. But your tables are incorrect. What is the meaning of _num_arearegion_ in the table Region? And the table Areas require an foreign key to the table Region to indicate the owner Region for the Area. And if you want to select an area when you select an house then you need to have the foreign key to the Area also in the table House

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An house is located in a region (1-1 relationship), a Region can have one or more Areas (1-n relationship), an Area belongs to one and only one Region* with these relationships you have your database schema wrong. You need something like this (because obviously an house could be located in only one Area)

```
1) House:
| ID_house | House_names | ID_region | ID_areas |
--------------------------------------------------
|   int    |    names    |    int     | int      |

2) Region:
| ID_region | Nameofregions |
-----------------------------
|   int     |    names      |

3) Areas:
| ID_areas | Area_names | ID_region |
-------------------------------------
|   int   |    names    | int       |
```

Now when you get the id for the house you have also the id for the region and the area.

```
private void cmbHouse_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbHouse.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // Each item in a combobox binded to a datatable is a DataRowView
        // If we get this object we can access all the columns from that row
        DataRowView rv = cmbHouse.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        // Extract the fk for the region and the area
        int id_region = Convert.ToInt32(rv["ID_region"]);
        int id_area = Convert.ToInt32(rv["ID_area"]);

        // at startup you have already filled the combo with the regions,
        // so there is no need to look again in the database for the region
        // Just set the current selected value to the region
        cmbRegion.SelectedValue = num_region;

        // the same happens for the Areas combo. It is already filled with the 
        // areas, but here we should really have only the areas that belongs to 
        // the selected region not all the area to avoid problems 
        // (so remove the initial filling and do it only when the user choose an House)
        // Query for all areas belonging to the selected region
        string areaSql = @"SELECT * FROM Areas 
                           WHERE ID_Region=@reg";
        OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand(areaSql, connection);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", num_region);
        OleDbDataAdapter danum_area = new OleDbDataAdapter(com2);
        DataTable tablenum_area = new DataTable();
        danum_area.Fill(tablenum_area);

        // Always put the Datasource after the setting for DisplayMember and ValueMember 
        // to avoid performance drops and problems if there is a SelectedIndexChanged event
        cmbArea.DisplayMember = "Names_OfAreas";
        cmbArea.ValueMember = "ID_areas";
        cmbArea.DataSource = tablenum_area;

        // last step is setting the SelectedValue on the cmbArea to the house's area 
        cmbArea.SelectedValue = id_area;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this sign" @" mean in query? And what functionality does Parameters.AddWithValue perform?

Comment: The  @ symbol inside the command text is the parameter placeholder. The database receives the parameters and apply the correct logic to use  the parameter values in the data operation requested. Adding a parameter to the command's parameters collection helps you to avoid cumbersome string concatenations often used to hack database with a tecnique called Sql Injection. A parameter avoids also parsing problems like correct interpretation for dates and decimal values. Moreover, if the command text is fixed the database engine could reuse previously parsed queries with improvement in performances.